# Spring DATA JPA and REST repository in separate related modules (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Is it possible to split jpa repository and rest repository(annotation) of the same entity to separate modules?

Main pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>


<dependency>
    <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
    <artifactId>database</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Module1(rest api) pom.xml
Distinct Spring Boot App

```
...
<parent>
    <artifactId>a.b.c</artifactId>
    <groupId>main</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependency>
    <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
    <artifactId>database</artifactId>
</dependency>
...
```

Module2 (web service) pom.xml
Distinct Spring Boot App

```
   ...
<parent>
    <artifactId>a.b.c</artifactId>
    <groupId>main</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependency>
    <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
    <artifactId>database</artifactId>
</dependency>
...
```

Database module pom.xml

```
..
<packaging>jar</packaging>
...

public interface MyJpaEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity,String> {
}
```

If i annotate this repo as @RepositoryRestResource this will expose REST api in both modules above with different base url..

But i whant enable classic Jpa Dao in Module1 (without REST) and Jpa Dao with REST in Module2

How i can configure that?